# regex in Java with .replaceAll and .split

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to know which regex I must use. The code inside a method is:

```java
while( (line = bReader.readLine()) != null){
    line2 = line.replaceAll("[\\)][\\|]","R");
    numbers = line2.split("[\\|]");
}
int num = numbers.length;
```

What I want is that when `line` equals

```
(A#,A#,A#),(B#,B#,C#),(B#,B#,C#),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|(Ab,Ab,Ab),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|
```

it must return num = `0` because all instances of `)|` are replaced by `R` and there is no `|` left. What I get is num = `1`.

When `line` equals

```
(A#,A#,A#),(B#,B#,C#),(B#,B#,C#),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|A#,B#,C#,D#, E#,F#,G#,  |  ,A,  , ,   ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , ,   ,  ,  ,  |
```

it must return num = `2` because there are two instances of `|` after replacing the `)|` by `R`. What I get here is indeed num = `2`. I hope someone can give me the solution.

Comment: `line2.split("[\\|]");` escaping here is redundant as the meta character is already in character class. `line2.split("[|]");` is fine . :)

Comment: I didn't see any problem, the first return 1, because the array has only one element, the string with "R". the 2nd has two elements, so number=2.

Comment: When you split on a character that doesn't exist you will get the original `String` back in a one element `Array`. More generally if you split a `String` with one delimiter in it you get back an `Array` size 2, one with two delimiters will give back an `Array` size 3. See a pattern here?

Comment: I expect that the first string returns 0 because it has only instances of )| which are replaced by R. 0 is what I want to get.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find out how many `|` marks exists in String that are not predicted by `)` then you can remove these marks and check how length of string changed. To detect such pipes you can use [negative look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
int num = s.length() - s.replaceAll("(?<![)])[|]", "").length();
```

Comment: Very neat - didn't think of just comparing lengths after `replaceAll`. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you split a `String` on a delimiter that doesn't exist then you will get back the original `String`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString("My string without pipes".split("\\|")));
}
```

Output:

```
[My string without pipes]
```

If you try and split on a character that the string ends with you **do not** get an empty `String` in the `Array`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString("My string ending in pipe|".split("\\|")));
}
```

Output:

```
[My string ending in pipe]
```

All that happens is the delimiter at the end is dropped.

So your logic is wrong. The reason you got the correct answer in your second check is not because the check is correct but because the pipe happened to be at the end.

Generally, you will not get the number of delimiters in a `String` using `spilt`, you will get the number `+1` unless your `String` starts or ends with the delimiter - in which case it will simply be dropped.

What you need to do is use regex to search for all pipes not preceded by a closing parenthesis. You can do this with negative lookbehind:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    final String s1 = "(A#,A#,A#),(B#,B#,C#),(B#,B#,C#),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|(Ab,Ab,Ab),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|";
    final String s2 = "(A#,A#,A#),(B#,B#,C#),(B#,B#,C#),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|A#,B#,C#,D#, E#,F#,G#,  |  ,A,  , ,   ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , ,   ,  ,  ,  |";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\))\\|");
    int count = 0;
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s1);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        ++count;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
    count = 0;
    matcher.reset(s2);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        ++count;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Output:

```
0
2
```